# PHP, Dropbox API, OAuth signature and Non-latin symbols

Tags: php, oauth, dropbox-api

I have the PHP application integrated with Dropbox API. It worked good but since some time ago it stopped to work with non-latin symbols. 
For example, if i try to create a dropbox folder with the API and use Cyrillic letters in folder name then API requests fail with error **{"error": "Unauthorized"}**

I have the PHP function

```
function createOAuthSignature($apiurl, $params, $oauth_secret, $oauth_token_secret, $method='GET'){
    $urlencoded_apiurl = urlencode($apiurl);
    $urlencoded_params = urlencode($params);

    $basestring = $method .'&'.$urlencoded_apiurl.'&'.$urlencoded_params;
    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $basestring, $oauth_secret.'&'.$oauth_token_secret, true));

    $oauth_signature = urlencode($oauth_signature);

    return $oauth_signature;
}
```

And the calling code is

```
    $fullname = $parent . $foldername;
    $fullnameEnc = rawurlencode($fullname);
    $apiurl = $this->api_url .'fileops/create_folder/';

    $params  = 'oauth_consumer_key='.$this->oauth_consumer_key
        .'&oauth_nonce='. $this->createNonce()
        .'&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1'
        .'&oauth_timestamp='. time()
        .'&oauth_token='.$oauth_token
        .'&oauth_version=1.0'
        .'&path='. $fullnameEnc
        .'&root=dropbox';

    $oauth_signature = $this->createOAuthSignature($apiurl, $params, $this->oauth_secret, $oauth_token_secret);

    $params .= '&oauth_signature='.$oauth_signature;
    $action = $apiurl .'?'. $params;
    $s = $this->curl->get($action);
```

What can be the problem there? I presume it is related to signature generating. But what is wrong there? This code worked fine just couple weeks ago.

Thanks

Comment: We'll look into it, but we highly recommend using PLAINTEXT signing instead: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/ (It's much easier to debug and implement.)

Answer (score 0):

As Greg mentioned in a comment above, we're investigating, but if you want to switch to PLAINTEXT signing, it's quite easy. Change `createOAuthSignature` to just do this:

```
function createOAuthSignature($apiurl, $params, $oauth_secret, $oauth_token_secret, $method='GET'){
    return urlencode($oauth_secret.'&'.$oauth_token_secret);
}
```

And in the calling code, change the signature method to `PLAINTEXT`:

```
$params = ...
    .'&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT'
    ...
```